# Serve Javascript with PHP: Return/Echo URL/URI

Tags: javascript, php

**EDIT: Missed the echo statement!**

**EDIT2: Added missing paranthesis!**

**EDIT3: Found the solution. See below!**

What I am trying to achieve is this:

1. Dynamically create a Javascript-file with PHP
2. Serve Javascript-file as .js as embeddable Javascript on different URLs
3. Dynamically add Page Name and Page URL information inside the JS to be used in Javascript

Currently I do the following:

**code.php**

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/x-javascript"); ?>
/*
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;?>
*/
/*
<?php
$func = new Functions;
echo $func->getPageURL();
echo $func->getPageName();
?>
*/
var fred;
...
```

**class.functions.php**

```
<?php
class Functions {
    function getPageURL() {
        $isHTTPS = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on");
        $port = (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]) && ((!$isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") || ($isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443")));
        $port = ($port) ? ':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : '';
        $data = ($isHTTPS ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$port.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

        return $data;
    }

    function getPageName() {
        $data = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);

        return $data;
    }

}
```

Whenever someone triggers my script-embed code I route them to my **code.php**. Example:

```
<script src="//servingdomain/dynamic/123.js"></script>
```

Now, my code.php does a great job, but returns me this:

```
/*
servingdomain/dynamic/123.js
*/
/*
https://servingdomain/dynamic/123.js
index.php
*/

var fred;
...
```

Unfortunately my *getPageURL* und *getPageName* are not executed properly, but I am failing to understand why.

I am aiming to get this as output:

```
/*
servingdomain/dynamic/123.js
*/
/*
https://otherdomain/blog/awesome-article (page-url)
Awesome Article to read (page-name)
*/

var fred;
...
```

How should I takle this problem and get this working correctly either by clean code or dirty workaround ... I am aware of *window.location.pathname* and *window.location.href* in Javascript, but I need those to be passed in PHP, since I need to reuse this information to generate dynamic code in code.php.

**Solution**

Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] gives correct referrer and running that through

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$func = new Functions;
echo $func->getPageTitle($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

**class.functions.php**

```
function getPageTitle($url){
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
https://otherdomain/blog/awesome-article (page-url)
Awesome Article to read (page-name)
```

Comment: `echo $purl = $func->getPageURL;
echo $pname = $func->getPageName;`

Comment: sorry, comes up empty as well... ;(

Comment: found a solution: edited the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] gives correct referrer

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$func = new Functions;
echo $func->getPageTitle($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Running that through this function

**class.functions.php**

```
function getPageTitle($url){
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
https://otherdomain/blog/awesome-article (page-url)
Awesome Article to read (page-name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$func = new Functions;
$purl = $func->getPageURL()."\n";//use () 
$pname = $func->getPageName();
echo $purl;
echo $pname;
?>
```

Comment: nailed it! Missed the paranthesis! Unfortunately the function doesn't return the page name nor the page url, just the script url and the script name (comes up as index.php). See updated question.

Comment: @DKOATED can you see the output `print_r($_SERVER);`? you can understand what will you get from those variables.

Comment: Yep, but unfortunately $_SERVER ain't providing me with the embedded page URL. if microsoft.com embeds the JS, I want to get microsoft.com's URL and Page name, not the JS domain.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is executed just fine, but it just doesn't have any result. You need to write out the values to the file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/x-javascript"); ?>
/*
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;?>
*/
/*
<?php
$func = new Functions;
$purl = $func->getPageURL;
$pname = $func->getPageName;

printf("%s\n", $purl);
printf("%s\n", $pname);
?>
*/
var fred;
...
```

This will write the values of those variables to the javascript file.

Note that if you want to use these values in the javascript code, you need to assign them to a javascript variable like this, outside of javascript comments:

```
printf("var pageName='%s'\n", $pname);
```

That way, you can use `pageName` in your javascript.

Comment: sorry, comes up empty as well... ;(

Comment: The parentheses like @Amit Garg said were missing